# How to load static images on ExpressJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

so I have this node/express api that serve MySQL database, has json output like this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Laptop Lenovo",
  serial: "123-456",
  tag: "IT-CL-22052018-001",
  image: "/public/images/lenovo.jpg"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Desktop Dell",
  serial: "456-123",
  tag: "IT.CD.19052018-002",
  image: "public/images/dell.jpg"
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "Laptop Dell",
  serial: "909090",
  tag: "IT.CL.01052018.002",
  image: "http://localhost:8000/images/ldell.jpg"
 }
]
```

I tried this express functions each one of it:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(dir));
```

And the only way my React app can display the image is by using the full url on the database, like #3.

How I can display the image without using the full url?

Edit: Add Render Function

```
render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map(itemList => {
      let item = itemList;
      return (
        // <div className="tile">
        <div className="card margin-all">
          <div className="card-content">
            <div className="media">
              <div>
                <figure className="image is-96x96">
                  <img src={item.image} />
                </figure>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h4>Nama:  {item.name} </h4>
              <h4>Nomor Seri:  {item.serial} </h4>
              <h4>ID Tag:  {item.tag} </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        // </div>
      );
    })
  }
}
```

[Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/059JT.jpg)

Comment: show render function

Comment: Add in the question

Comment: from where react (front end) is served? from expressjs? if you are running express and react as separate servers you have to give full path.

Comment: express on port 8000 and react on port 3000. What happened if I deploy both on my own server?

Comment: In that case how can you use /public(express server) relative path from react code? you should use full path only. or move your images to reactjs server

Comment: Both servers are different. you should use full url only.

Comment: Ok noted that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by adding a proxy to React app, I don't need to provide full url to the link.

If the express port is 8000, then put this line in the package.json of the React App, not the Node app.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

Now I can use images/name.jpg and the image will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The route for static assets is `/static/` so I assume you must call the images like this (e.g. #2)

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

But you're requesting it via `/public/`

```
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Desktop Dell",
  serial: "456-123",
  tag: "IT.CD.19052018-002",
  image: "static/images/dell.jpg"
}
```

So if you want the path from your origin JSON get working change it to

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

**From express.js documentation:**
http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve

Comment: can you confirm folder public contains e.g. images/dell.jpg?

Comment: Should I put the images in public/images or public/static/images?

Comment: into `public/images/...` on your filesystem and the middleware makes it available over http at `/static/images/...`

Comment: what do you mean with gone?

Comment: Sorry, I meant previously, #3 always display the image no matter which function I use, now with your suggestion, app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  it doesn't show up.

Comment: because the path has changed if you've moved it to `public`subdirectory

Comment: I add a link to the pict to confirm the image

Answer (score 0):

For express middleware `app.use(express.static('public'))` is fine, problem is you need to use correct path. In you json data, image is `public/images/dell.jpg` which should be `/public/images/dell.jpg` but you can use

```
<img src={ '/' + item.image} />
```

as well, hope this will help